# ABRecordGetRecordID returns -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I am trying to get the ABRecordID of a record, but it always returns -1.
Here is my code:

```
 NSNumber *recordId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];
```

I can retrieve other informations without any problems :/ Any solutions?

Comment: -1 is returned when the record hasn't been saved to the database. See the docs for `ABRecordGetRecordID`.

Comment: OK I see, but I retrieve the entry from the iPhone Simulator, is this a bug then? Or should I use a different property to identify the ABRecordRef?

Comment: I have the same problem on iOS 8 on Simulator and on device.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to request authorization (`ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`) to be able to get a record identifier. Otherwise you just get an `ABPersonRef` with a copy of the data.